# TikZ graphs vs. czech babel

Tags: babel, tikz-graphs

I´ve got problems with combination of TikZ´s graphs library and czech babel. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

  \usepackage[czech]{babel}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (a) {a};
      \node (b) [right=of a] {b};
      \node (c) [right=of b] {c};
      \node (d) [below=of b] {d};
        \graph{a->{b,c} -> d};
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My output is this:

[image]

(Btw for desired image see PGFManual site 209 but it should be easy)I also tried \graph[use existing nodes] but the result was just this:

[image]

I saw here advice to use `\usetikzlibrary{graphs,babel}` but my MixTex just came up with:

I can't find file `tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex`.

So is there some way how to force these graphs to cooperate?

Comment: My miktex finds tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex without problems. Is your pgf version up-to-date?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

you need to add TikZ library `babel`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,% <-- added
                graphs,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node (b) [right=of a] {b};
\node (c) [right=of b] {c};
\node (d) [below=of b] {d};
    \graph{a->{b,c} -> d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```